Expressiveness in arithmetic
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a formal system for arithmetic (e.g. $P$ or $PA$), $f:N^q\rightarrow N^p$ a function of $N^q$ on $N^ p$ and $\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ a formula of $\mathcal{S}$ with $p$ free variables.
When is $\alpha(f(\mathbf{x}))$ expressible in $\mathcal{S}$? That is to say:
For which functions $f:N^q\rightarrow N^p$ and formulas $\alpha(\mathbf{x})$, with $p$ free variables, is there a formula $\alpha_f(\mathbf{y}) $ in $\mathcal{S}$, with $q$ free variables, such that the formula:
$$``\alpha_f(\mathbf{a})\Leftrightarrow \alpha(f(\mathbf{a}))"$$
be provable in $\mathcal{S}$ for each $\mathbf{a}\in N^q$ ?.

It would seem difficult to provide any other criterion than the defining property. In general, it will depend in intricate detail on $\alpha$ and $f$. Of course, for any definable $f$ this will be possible, but not only these, since perhaps $\alpha$ depends only on some of the variables, or perhaps the values of $f(\textbf{a})$ become related in a way that makes $\alpha(f(x))$ expressible even when $f$ is not. So what kind of answer are you seeking?

I think this property must be valid for every recursive primitive function, but I don't know if it is true or if there is any proof in that sense.

Let me observe that every total function $f$ that is representable in PA has your property with respect to every formula $\alpha$ expressible in the language of arithmetic. This includes every primitive recursive function and indeed every total computable function.
Recall that a (total) function $f$ on $\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}\N$ is representable in $\newcommand\PA{\text{PA}}\PA$, if there is a formula $\psi(x,y)$ in the language of arithmetic such that $f(a)=b\iff\PA\vdash\psi(a,b)$ for every $a,b\in\N$, and $f(a)\neq b\iff\PA\vdash\neg\psi(a,b)$. Every computable total function is representable in PA because we can take the formula $\psi(x,y)$ to assert that the given program on input $x$ gives output $y$, and PA will prove that every halting computation gives the output that it does in fact give. Conversely, every representable total function is computable, because on input $x$ we can search for proofs of a suitable instance $\psi(x,y)$ to find the value $y=f(x)$.
For the question, what I claim is that every total function $f:\N\to\N$ that is representable in PA will have your property that $\alpha(f(x))$ is expressible for every formula $\alpha$ in the language of arithmetic. (And similarly in higher arities.)
To see this, suppose that $f$ is a representable total function. We may find a formula $\psi(x,y)$ representing it, such that furthermore the relation defined by $\psi(x,y)$ is provably functional. It follows that the relation $\alpha(f(x))$ is expressible by the formula $\alpha_f(x)=\exists y\ [\psi(x,y)\wedge\alpha(y)]$, and PA will prove every instance of $\alpha_f(a)\iff\alpha(f(a))$, as desired.
However, there are many more instances of your property than these. Indeed, every function $f$ has your property with respect to some formulas $\alpha$, since $\alpha(f(x))$ could be tautologically true, or false, or whatever, making this relation trivially expressible. Or for example, perhaps $f$ is noncomputable and nonrepresentable, but $f(x)$ is always even, which could make $\alpha(f(x))$ trivial if $\alpha(y)$ is trivial when $y$ is even.
Because of these kinds of examples, I do not expect a tidy necessary and sufficient condition that differs substantially from the property as you have defined it.
